# How to parse a configuration file (kind of a CSV format) using LUA

Tags: string, lua

I am using LUA on a small ESP8266 chip, trying to parse a text string that looks like the one below. I am very new at LUA, and tried many similar scripts found at this forum.

```
data="
-- String to be parsed\r\n
Tiempo1,20\r\n
Tiempo2a,900\r\n
Hora2b,27\r\n
Tiempo2b,20\r\n
Hora2c,29\r\n
Tiempo2c,18\r\n"
```

My goal would be to parse the string, and return all the configuration pairs (name/value).
If needed, I can modify the syntax of the config file because it is created by me.
I have been trying something like this:

```
var1,var2 = data:match("([Tiempo2a,]), ([^,]+)")
```

But it is returning nil,nil. I think I am on the very wrong way to do this.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use gmatch and parse the values excluding non-printable characters (\r\n) at the end of the line or use %d+

```
local data=[[
-- String to be parsed
Tiempo1,20
Tiempo2a,900
Hora2b,27
Tiempo2b,20
Hora2c,29
Tiempo2c,18]]

local t = {}
for k,v in data:gmatch("(%w-),([^%c]+)") do
   t[#t+1] = { k, v }
   print(k,v)
end
```

Comment: Excellent @Mike-V that worked perfectly. After the for loop I looked for every specific configuration variable, and got the value. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JotaJotaGon You can vote the post and mark as answered [/welcome/](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)